# ¿Cómo firmar correctamente archivo XML "CAF" con caracteres especiales?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Tengo armado todo un proceso de emisión de DTE (documentos tributarios electrónicos) en Chile. Hasta la fecha no he tenido inconvenientes con la firma de los timbres y tampoco con la firma del documento en sí.

Resulta que hay un contribuyente que tiene doble comillas en su razón social, por lo que al enviar el DTE firmado, el SII me responde: *(CAF-3-514) Firma del CAF incorrecta*

Aplico correctamente el Encoding ISO-8859-1 y nunca he tenido problemas con las tildes o eñes, pero no puedo resolverlo cuando hay una **doble comilla**.

El archivo XML es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AUTORIZACION>
<CAF version="1.0">
<DA>
<RE>11111111-1</RE>
<RS>SOCIEDAD BERNARDO O&quot;HIGGINS SPA</RS>
<TD>33</TD>
<RNG><D>101</D><H>200</H></RNG>
<FA>2020-05-28</FA>
<RSAPK><M>t6ldOQd1Mz+1tiYhaMvVCKeAyT2vQK4rqYCHtbMDWIAHBGwI3mr1mmgLUpXKfvisRl1pTY2RXWdZVd6vE12PSw==</M><E>Aw==</E></RSAPK>
<IDK>100</IDK>
</DA>
<FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">UQ85YCoqC+pBw7kjzU0g+0uufqKKg759DapDJP4Bt4LMk1mK4330cgBPpVh/iUo5oC9TxINqo0icwFYiAabskw==</FRMA>
</CAF>
<RSASK>-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOQIBAAJBALepXTkHdTM/tbYmIWjL1QingMk9r0CuK6mAh7WzA1iABwRsCN5q
9ZpoC1KVyn74rEZdaU2NkV1nWVXerxNdj0sCAQMCQHpw6NCvo3d/znluwPCH41sa
Vdt+dNXJcnEAWnkiAjr+4v/O/o8lhCUGHFaf/0B+1jp2kTnb7b/A4qrd9fxFs7sC
IQDm1L63s29TnXKNkSrlDPGRuqBa0IsmFoXM82Xp0aVhfwIhAMuv9tNUQ1vFbFM/
euaRSNk0CzSmOIanQDhiK9RHT6A1AiEAmeMpz8z04mj3CQtx7gihC9HAPIsHbrmu
iKJD8TZuQP8CIQCHyqSM4teSg52M1PyZtjCQzVzNxCWvGirQQXKNhN/AIwIgXDO7
2/zf8L8fGm6nrDl56Oiybnq0PIg67W4FJ3NBXxI=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</RSASK>

<RSAPUBK>-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSQAwRgJBALepXTkHdTM/tbYmIWjL1QingMk9r0Cu
K6mAh7WzA1iABwRsCN5q9ZpoC1KVyn74rEZdaU2NkV1nWVXerxNdj0sCAQM=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
</RSAPUBK>
</AUTORIZACION>
```

En la etiqueta RS encontramos lo siguiente:

```
<RS>SOCIEDAD BERNARDO O&quot;HIGGINS SPA</RS>
```

Para la serialización utilizo C#:

```
public static T DeserializeRawWithoutEncoding<T>(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Pero al deserializar `&quot;` se transforma automáticamente a `\"`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que ambos casos son válidos pues es sólo una interpretación del Encoding, y la firma del timbre  la realiza bien según los validadores que tengo implementados. Además cuando tengo problemas en la firma del timbre, el SII indica el siguiente error: `(TED-2-510) REPARO- Firma Timbre Electrónico` Incorrecta
**Y este no ha sido el caso.**

El XML final generado es el siguiente:

```
<TED version="1.0">
<DD>
<RE>76521854-3</RE>
<TD>33</TD>
<F>101</F>
<FE>2020-05-30</FE>
<RR>66666666-6</RR>
<RSR>Razon Social de Cliente</RSR>
<MNT>0</MNT>
<IT1>Cajón AFECTO</IT1>
<CAF version="1.0">
<DA>
<RE>76521854-3</RE>
<RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O"HIGGINS SPA</RS>
<TD>33</TD>
<RNG>
<D>101</D>
<H>200</H>
</RNG>
<FA>2020-05-28</FA>
<RSAPK>
<M>t6ldOQd1Mz+1tiYhaMvVCKeAyT2vQK4rqYCHtbMDWIAHBGwI3mr1mmgLUpXKfvisRl1pTY2RXWdZVd6vE12PSw==</M>
<E>Aw==</E>
</RSAPK>
<IDK>100</IDK>
</DA>
<FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">UQ85YCoqC+pBw7kjzU0g+0uufqKKg759DapDJP4Bt4LMk1mK4330cgBPpVh/iUo5oC9TxINqo0icwFYiAabskw==</FRMA>
</CAF>
<TSTED>2020-05-30T20:37:53</TSTED>
</DD>
<FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">tVLkmiiS4+f2df6VSAuUbtBFzfBREEPu/xY2425y6+GOoBY7RJ44GN0sJOWZV4gqMrVm1bYUFR5PsMFuxyGPQA==</FRMT>
</TED>
```

Como podrán fijarse en la etiqueta `<RS>`, `&quot;` es reemplazado por `\"`. Es por eso que asumo que el SII me está reclamando que la firma del CAF no es válida. `(CAF-3-514) Firma del CAF incorrecta`

Este XML es generado después de serializar un objeto `TED` de esta forma:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "";
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(tempFilePath, settings))
{
      XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());                                                  
      s.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
}
```

Acciones que he realizado sin frutos:

1. Reemplazar `\"` por `&quot;` de distintas maneras. Directo con `string.Replace()` y con `SecurityElement.Escape()`, sin embargo el SII sigue respondiendo con error y generalmente también con error de firma en el timbre. Esto también ha provocado que la etiqueta termine como `<RS>SOCIEDAD BERNARDO O&amp;quot;HIGGINS SPA</RS>` malinterpretando la intención.
2. En todos los procedimientos utilizo Encoding ISO-8859-1, y los he ido variando por UTF-8 sin tener ninguna mejora al respecto.

El SII dispone de un [manual público (página 20)](http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/instructivo_emision.pdf) donde se indica que estos caracteres deben ser reemplazados, pero al hacerlo sigo con el problema.

¿Cómo resolverlo en C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo tuve el mismo problema, estuvimos todo el dia probando y nada el CAF se daña cuando se baja del SII, finalmente conversamos con el cliente  y le pedimos que cambie la razon social, eliminando las comillas del nombre como es empresa en un dia no debe hacer escritura, se puede hacer por intenet

Comment: Sí, al final tuve que hacer lo mismo. Se solicitó eliminar la comilla doble. Un parto. Por ser la única respuesta y no haber una solución te he marcado como respuesta aceptada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No debe ser considerado como una solución correcta cambiar la Razón Social en SII.

La respuesta a este problema es leer con el encoding adecuado el archivo, el cual es el "ISO-8859-1", el XML del CAF generado de SII no lo indica correctamente en el tag "xml".

```
DeserializeRawWithEncoding(filePath, "iso-8859-1");

public static T DeserializeRawWithEncoding<T>(string filePath, string encoding)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, encoding))
    {
        obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Dependiendo de que libreria utilizes, no siempre es posible forzar otro encoding al leer el archivo, porque puede ser que siempre lo lea desde el tag "xml".

En este caso bastaría con editar el tag antes de importarlo.

Ejemplo con Chilkat en C#:

```
// Arreglar tag xml para indicar encoding
Chilkat.StringBuilder sbCAF = new Chilkat.StringBuilder();
sbCAF.LoadFile("CAF.xml", "ISO-8859-1");
sbCAF.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
sbCAF.WriteFile("CAF_CORRECTO.xml", "ISO-8859-1", false);

// Ahora la carga se realiza con el encoding correcto
Chilkat.Xml xmlCAF = new Chilkat.Xml();
bool success = xmlCAF.LoadXmlFile("CAF_CORRECTO.xml");
if (success == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CAF cargado correctamente.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya intenté hacer todo lo que me comentaste, de todas maneras cuando lo retome intentaré nuevamente con Chilkat. Muchas gracias.